# Worst-case sparse graphs for Hopcroft-Karp Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Of large sparse biparite graphs (say degree 4) with N verticies, roughly speaking, which of them cause the worst case running time of the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)? What is their general structure and architecture, and why does it cause a problem?

Further, in many implementations the DFS part is implemented using recursion, eg from Wikipedia:

```
function DFS (v)
    if v != NIL
        for each u in Adj[v]
            if Dist[ Pair_G2[u] ] == Dist[v] + 1
                if DFS(Pair_G2[u]) == true
                    Pair_G2[u] = v
                    Pair_G1[v] = u
                    return true
        Dist[v] = ∞
        return false
    return true
```

What is the approximate maximum depth of the recursion in the worst case?

Comment: The maximum recursion depth of DFS is $n$; the DFS tree might consist of a single (Hamiltonian) path.